# Objective-C - Translate string to different characters using a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an iOS program that takes a string from the user, splits the string up by character, and then uses each character as a key to grab a seperate (morse code) character from a dictionary. I'm having issues regarding the char*s and strings, and I am receiving errors having to do with improper types and not finding the key in the array. Thoughts please? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  MorseCodeTranslator
//
//  Created by Mitch  on 4/30/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Mitch . All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userInput;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputField;

- (IBAction)translateUserString:(UIButton *)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)translateUserString:(UIButton *)sender {
    BOOL stringPresent = (self.userInput.text.length > 0);

    if (stringPresent) {
        NSDictionary *morseCharacterKey = @{
                                           @"A" : @".-",
                                           @"B" : @"-...",
                                           @"C" : @"-.-.",
                                           @"D" : @"-..",
                                           @"E" : @".",
                                           @"F" : @"..-.",
                                           @"G" : @"--.",
                                           @"H" : @"....",
                                           @"I" : @"..",
                                           @"J" : @".---",
                                           @"K" : @"-.-",
                                           @"L" : @".-..",
                                           @"M" : @"--",
                                           @"N" : @"-.",
                                           @"O" : @"---",
                                           @"P" : @".--.",
                                           @"Q" : @"--.-",
                                           @"R" : @".-.",
                                           @"S" : @"...",
                                           @"T" : @"-",
                                           @"U" : @"..-",
                                           @"V" : @"...-",
                                           @"W" : @".--",
                                           @"X" : @"-..-",
                                           @"Y" : @"-.--",
                                           @"Z" : @"--..",
                                           @"1" : @".----",
                                           @"2" : @"..---",
                                           @"3" : @"...--",
                                           @"4" : @"....-",
                                           @"5" : @".....",
                                           @"6" : @"-....",
                                           @"7" : @"--...",
                                           @"8" : @"---..",
                                           @"9" : @"----.",
                                           @"0" : @"-----",
                                           @" " : @"/",
                                           @"," : @"--..--",
                                           @"." : @".-.-.-",
                                           @"?" : @"..--..",
                                           @"\'" : @".----.",
                                           @"!" : @"-.-.--",
                                           @"/" : @"-..-.",
                                           @"(" : @"-.--.",
                                           @")" : @"-.--.-",
                                           @"&" : @".-...",
                                           @":" : @"---...",
                                           @";" : @"-.-.-.",
                                           @"=" : @"-...-",
                                           @"+" : @".-.-.",
                                           @"-" : @"-....-",
                                           @"_" : @"..--.-",
                                           @"\"" : @".-..-.",
                                           @"$" : @"...-..-",
                                           @"@" : @".--.-."
        };

        NSString *userString = self.userInput.text;
        NSString *outputString;

        for (int i = 0; userString.length > i; i++){
            char userCharacter = [userString characterAtIndex:i];

            char morseCharacter = [morseCharacterKey objectForKey:morseCharacterKey[userCharacter]];
            outputString stringByAppendingString:[morseCharacter];

            self.outputField.text = outputString;
        }

    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should use `NSString`:

```
for (int i = 0; userString.length > i; i++) {
        NSString *userCharacter = [userString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];

        NSString *morseCharacter = morseCharacterKey[userCharacter];
        outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingString:morseCharacter];

        NSLog(outputString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This appears to work great... everything compiles... but it aborts with an NSException when I try to actually run it.

Comment: what is your input string and what is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

So:

```
@"A"
```

Is an `NSString` literal.  So your dictionary keys:

```
NSDictionary *morseCharacterKey = @{
                                   @"A" : @".-",
                                   ...
```

Are `NSString*`s.  Which is fine, because keys are required to be objects.

You're getting the character as a `char`, which is not an object, and even if it was it isn't the same object as you used for your keys.

Instead what you want to do is something like this:

```
NSRange range;
range.location = i;
range.length = 1;
NSString* userCharacter = [userString substringWithRange:range];
```

And use `userCharacter` as your key.  Note that your values are also `NSString*`s, so you should store the result of your dictionary lookup in an `NSString` as well.

Comment: One comment, perhaps it should be `[[userString substringWithRange:range] uppercaseString];` because his keys are all uppercase.

Comment: Yeah, that's an implementation detail, an input sanitization detail, what have you.  Basically outside the scope of the question and the answer, but a good detail none the less.  Feel free, as always, to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be working with `char`. Try this:

```
    NSString *userString = self.userInput.text;
    NSMutableString *outputString = [NSMutableString string];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < userString.length; i++) {
        NSString *letter = [userString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];

        NSString *morse = morseCharacterKey[letter];
        [outputString appendingString:morse];
    }

    self.outputField.text = outputString;
```

Comment: I think it needs to call `uppercaseString` somewhere to account for the dictionary's keys.  Perhaps, `morseCharacterKey[letter.uppercaseString]`?

Comment: @Logan Good point. If the user can type lowercase letters, this code should convert `userString` to uppercase.

Comment: Thanks! This works great when it compiles. I'm recieving an NSException when I run the code that might be unrelated?

Comment: That's not an error. That's a copy of some code from another answer.

Comment: This is what my code looks like at this point. The output is a timestamp and (null) for each letter I input, although there doesn't seem to be an issue with reading the dictionary.

Comment: NSString *userString = self.userInput.text;
        NSString *outputString;
        
        for (int i = 0; userString.length > i; i++) {
            NSString *userCharacter = [userString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
            
            NSString *morseCharacter = morseCharacterKey[userCharacter.uppercaseString];
            outputString = [outputString stringByAppendingString:morseCharacter];
            NSLog(@"%@", outputString);
            
            self.outputField.text = outputString;
            
        }
    }
}
@end

Comment: The other NSException error I was having was solved by resetting the connections to the storyboard. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Turns out I had failed to initialize the output string, which is important because I was appending it and it was adding to a null value. Fix was just a couple characters long. Thanks alot for all of your assistance!

Comment: If you look at the code in my answer, the output string is properly being initialized and appended to.

Answer (score 0):

Block based enumeration would clean this up a little bit.  Also a NSMutableString would be better then using stringByAppendingString.  Also since I use a mutableString we don't have to use the __block specify in order to append to it like we would if stringByAppending string was used.

```
NSString *string = @"...";
NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *value = morseCharacterKey[substring];
    [output appendString:value];
}];
```